# trouble writing a method to print an array of primes

Tags: java, arrays, primes

When I compile I get an error saying "cannot find symbol" pointing to my `arr.add(j)` line. Can someone explain what's wrong with my code?

```
public class MyClass {
    public static boolean IsPrime(int p) {
        for (int i = 2; i < p; i++) {
            if (p % i == 0 && i != p)
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static int[] GetPrimes(int n) {
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (IsPrime(j) {
                arr.add(j);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java ain't javascript: Arrays have no methods (beyond those inherited from Object, which are essentially useless).

Use a `List<Integer>` instead.

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
...
arr.add(j);
...
return Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Comment: Actually, array has `toString(), clone() ...` methods inherited from Object class.

Answer (score 0):

this line `arr.add(j);`have to be changed to `arr[j];` because you have an `array` not a `List` object.

Also your class name have to start with a character.